# understanding nested list from list with duplicated values

Tags: python, list

To get `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]`

from old_list = `[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]`

I found this answer:

```
new_list = []
for value in old_list:
    if new_list and new_list[-1][0] == value:
        new_list[-1].append(value)
    else:
        new_list.append([value])
```

I am trying to understand what is meaning of new_list[-1][0]
confusion came when I tried to run

```
new_list = []
new_list[-1] # shows index out of bounds
```

and `new_list and new_list[-1][0]` does not produce any error under if statement

What `new_list[-1][0]` is doing here.

Answer (score 1):

`new_list[-1][0]` retrieves the last element of `new_list`, which is itself a list and gets its first element.

`new_list and new_list[-1][0] == value` short circuits, so it does not try to access the last element if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`new_list[-1][0]` is checking for the first value in the last element of the list `new_list`.

**Example:**

For
`new_list = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]`

if you try `new_list[-1][0]`, you will get value `5`.

`[-1]` gets you the last element of the list and `[0]` gives you the first value.

So, `[-1]` gets you `[5,5,5,5,5]` and then [0] gives yoou `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Say we tried something on a normal list like this.

```
new_list = [1,2,3]
print(new_list[-1][0])
```

We are going to receive an error

```
    print(new_list[-1][0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

But if we try indexing that on lists of a list it will work.

```
new_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(new_list[-1][0])
```

no error, output is

```
4
```

Lets take a look into `list[-1][0]`. Basically, [-1] will get us the last element in a list. In this case it will give us the last list in our bigger list. Then the [0] will get us the first element in a list. So the order is `[4,5,6]` & `4`